# How to close tcp server socket correctly

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

can anyone explain me, what I am doing wrong with my tcp server termination?

In my program (single instance), I started another program which starts a tcp server. For the tcp server it is only allowed to listen to one connection.

After a connection was established between client and my server, a few messages are shared. As soon as the message protocoI has passed through, I want to terminate the server socket, reset my internal states and close my sub-programm.

After a few seconds, it will be possible to open my sub-programm again.
If so, I open the socket again... The same network device, the same ip address and the same port as before will be used...

My problem: my sub-programm crashes when running the 2nd time.

With netstat I analyzed my socket and found out, it stays in state LAST_ACK.
This can take more than 60 seconds (timeout?) till the socket is finally closed.

For closing the socket, I used the following code:

```
if (0 != shutdown(socketDescriptor_, SHUT_RDWR)) {
    std::cout << "Read/write of socket deactivated" << std::endl;
}
if (0 == close(socketDescriptor_)) {
    std::cout << "Socket is destroyed" << std::endl;
    socketDescriptor_ = -1;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Matthias

Comment: Your test for the result on `shutdown` is backwards - [it returns zero upon success](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html).

Comment: Ok, if I changed to (0 == shutdown), my socket will sty in "FIN_WAIT1", but nothing else happens.

Comment: Is there any possbility (e. g. socket options) to ignore LAST_ACK and FIN_WAIT steps, just terminate the socket immediately?